# Save new file in vim where filename is stored in a register?

Tags: vim

I have a file that stores filename and a word on content like

```
filename1 this is some content
filename2 this is some content
```

I have already written macro that would create new files and populate the field, The question that i have is while saving is it possible to save the file to `filename*` ? currently i have stored the filename to vim register but not sure on how to save to that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>` to insert variable or register contents:

```
:write <C-R>a<CR>
```

... but in a script, `:execute` must be used. All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables; for registers, use the special `@` sigil:

```
execute 'write' @a
```

To handle special characters in the filename, add this:

```
execute 'write' fnameescape(@a)
```

#### Alternative

If each line corresponds to a single file and its contents (and you have many such lines), creating a new buffer and saving it (in a macro) will take quite some time. You can alternatively use the low-level `writefile()` function and skip the buffer creation:

```
:global/^/ let [filename, content] = matchlist(getline('.'), '\(\S\+\)\s\(.*\)')[1:2] | call writefile([content], filename)
```

#### Does it have to be Vim?

Also, such a task might be easier to perform in a scripting language (often as a one-liner), e.g. in Python or Perl.

Comment: Hi this is exactly what i have been looking for. Its more about learning vim rather than using some other language. What i was trying to validate was if `macro` are session specific and can be used to create multiple files in a session. Seems like it would be possible. Hoping to use the same to create a lot of files like MVC faster :)

Comment: Thanks, glad I could help. Yes, macros are just like a sequence of typed keys. You can do anything in there.